# Java - Converting byte array to a python dictionary-like object

Tags: python, java, serial-port

I'm trying to migrate an application from Python to Java, which I'm a complete noob, but I have encountered a problem.

In python I receive bytes through the serial ports and I'm able to split the data in a single line by doing just like so:

```
temp = temp.decode("utf-8").split(',')
```

Example data:

> S,24,31479873,00000,00000,00000,3296,

So it'd be divided to a list of elements, like so:

> ['S', '24', '31479873', '00000', '00000', '00000', '3296', '\r\n']

And I'd be able to loop through a key list and relate that list to this split list. Appending the result to a list of dictionaries called "packages".

```
key = ["type", "line_number", "timestamp", "hits", "pulses", "hits_acc", "voltage", "unused"]
self.packages.append({key[i]:temp[i] for i in range(len(key))})
```

I want the exact same functionality in Java. Can anyone guide me through this? Sorry if I'm being too vague but I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Java.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create a csv structure keyed by column name. You could either roll your own using ```Map<String, List<String>>``` (keys are column headers, values are a list of column values) or use a csv API such as OpenCSV, which generally allow the data columns to be accessed using the column header as a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is strong typed language , so the code may seems a little complex, as follows:

```
String line = "S,24,31479873,00000,00000,00000,3296,x";
        String [] parts = line.split(",");
        String [] cols = {"type", "line_number", "timestamp", "hits", "pulses", "hits_acc", "voltage", "unused"};
        if (parts.length != cols.length) {
            System.out.println("Data invalid");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
            String key = cols[i];
            String val = parts[i];
            result.put(key, val);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this using a Stringbuffer since I'm receiving data from a serial interface. I think it'll work porperly now!